# modifications to a branch impacted master simultaneously while using git

Tags: git

When I was using git this morning, I found whatever modifications I had done to a local branch impacted local master branch at the same time, it seems that the two local branches are the same one. Now I can do nothing cause anything I do will modify the local master branch, can anyone help me get this through, thanks a lot.

Current status of local branch central-china-warehouse:
[image]

Current status of local branch master:
[image]

Looks exactly same. And if I undo add of a file, status of both two branches will change at the same time:
[image]

[image]

Really strange!!!

And took the advice from merlin2011, I've showed link information of all branches as below:

[image]
  I'm afraid nothing special showed. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Are you talking about `master` vs `origin/master`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a lot more information and perhaps the output of some simple commands like "git status" and the like.

Comment: are you saying that when you have a modified file and then switch branches with "git checkout" that the file stays modified?

Comment: @AndrewC:You are right.

Comment: You haven't modified anything on *either* branch. You have changes that you haven't committed yet.

Comment: Please also show the output of ls -i on that directory so we are sure there are no hard links either.

Comment: @hobbs:I've tried if you do a commit, status of both branches will change at the same time too.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure speculation, but the behavior described could result from one the following possibilities.

1. One of the two branches is symlinked to the other one, so that updates to one file under `.git/refs/heads` are reflected in the other one.
2. There a script somewhere running in the background that is keeping them in sync (some coworker is playing a prank.)

To investigate the former, more benign possibility, go into your directory, and `ls -l .git/refs/heads`. See if one of the branches is a symbolic link pointing at the other.

If that is the case, you can resolve it by first manually deleting the one that is a symlink, and then either re-creating it using `git checkout -b BranchName` from `master`, or just copying the `master` to the name again.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. Actually I mean every modification I made to a local branch impacted local master branch at the same time.

Comment: @tuanlong, To be clear, you have a local branch named something that is **not** `master`, and whenever you commit to that branch, the local `master` moves?

Comment: It's still not clear.  Post the commands you type and the output from them, and include `git rev-parse` for each branch before and after you commit.

Comment: I posted all pictures for illustration. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tuanlong, I updated the answer with some speculation. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @merlin2011:I followed your advice and printed the result above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have huge difficulties understanding how git works.

In git changes aren't bound to a specific branch. This means as long as you don't do a `git commit` these changes will stay in your worktree (the place where you work and all the checked out files sit).

In my opinion a simple `git commit` would be sufficent to solve your confusion; this will take all changes you recorded to the index via `git add` and create a *commit* which now is bound to a branch.
Obviously you have to execute this command on the branch you want to record the changes to.

To get a better understanding to how exactly you record changes in git take a look at the corresponding chapter [Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).